# Smoothly patching together polynomial level sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Apologies if this is too low-level; I wasn't sure whether it belonged here or on math.stackoverflow.

Say I have level sets for two polynomials of degree n on ℝ<sup>d</sup>. What constraints must they satisfy to ensure that, on their intersection, they agree to n<sup>th</sup> order? The motivation is from computer graphics, so I can make some simplifying assumptions (e.g. n and d small) if necessary.